# Prove f(x) is a probability density function (pdf)

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, density-function

So in order to prove that $f(x)=1/(x+1)^2$ $for$ $x>=0$ and $0$ $otherwise$ is a probability density function, it needs to satisfy the "properties" of a PDF which are:

1) $0<= f(x)$

2) $\int f(x) = 1$

3) $P(A) = P(a<=X<=b) = \int_A  f(x)$ $dx$

to prove each:

1) Can I just show that since $\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)=0$ and $f(0)$=1 and it's an obvious decreasing function (by graphing?) then $0<= f(x)$

2) $\int f(x) = \int_0^\infty 1/(x+)^2$ = -1/(x+1) = 0 - (-1) = 1

3) this is where I'm stuck. I don't quite know how to prove this property. I tried the following:

$P(A) = P(a<=X<=b) = P(X<=b) - P(X<a)= 1/(a+1) - 1/(b+1)$

$and$

$\int_a^b  f(x)$ $dx$ $= 1/(a+1) - 1/(b+1)$

is this the right way to do it?

Comment: your P(A) calculation is f(b) - f(a), while your integral is F(b) - F(a), they are not equivalent.

Comment: fixed it to be reflective of your comment. Hopefully that's the right way to do it. Thanks.

Comment: Please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question if necessary to fit the guidelines there (though you broadly seem to follow the guidelines on asking such questions).

Comment: As long as you do not define $P(A)$ it will be hard to prove 3. I think that you only need the first two properties and then you can define $P(x \in [a,b]) = \int_a^b f(x) dx$

Comment: (1) is trivial because $f(x)$ is the reciprocal of a non-zero square, whence it is positive.  (3) is the definition.  Thus, (2) is the only part of this question with any substance--and it's the part you have already answered!

Comment: Properties (1) and (2) exactly characterize PDFs. No idea what (3) even means.